# Making a UIBarButtonItem transparent in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, alpha, titlebar

How do I make a UIBarButtonItem's alpha be 0 in swift? I want it to fade in when a specific element appears on the screen. Does anybody know how to do this? Or any equally effective method would be great.

Answer (score 2):

The `UIBarButtonItem` is not a `UIView` so it doesn't have `alpha`.

Instead, you can make a `UIBarButtonItem` with custom view like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 30))
    button.hidden = true
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let view = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView
    view?.hidden = false
    view?.alpha = 0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
        view?.alpha = 1.0
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just create an IBOutlet of that button and in the code you can just do this:

```
import UIKit

class DemoViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var button : UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```